# join() function in Python 3 supports only strings?

Tags: python

Python 3, Windows 7. I found out that in Python 3 the `join()` function works only on strings (What!? Why?). I need it to work on anything.

Eg.

```
lista = [1,2,3,"hey","woot",2.44]
print (" ".join(lista))

1 2 3 hey woot 2.44
```

Also could anyone tell me why it supports ONLY strings?

Comment: Because `join()` is a string function... See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join.

Comment: If you just want to print, do - `print(*lista)` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar Thank you SOOO much on that tip. I will use it.

Comment: @SaeX although `join` is a string *method*, that's not *why* the elements in the iterable need to be strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It supporst only string becuase the **output of "".join() will be in string format**:

```
lista = [1,2,3,"hey","woot",2.44]
print (" ".join(map(str,lista)))
print type(" ".join(map(str,lista)))
1 2 3 hey woot 2.44
<type 'str'>
```

This is due to fact you can not append int/float and string:

i.e.)

```
"a"+2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-232-902dbc9d2568> in <module>()
----> 1 "a"+2

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects 

lista = [1,2,3,"hey","woot",2.44]
print (" ".join(lista))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-235-f57f2c8c638f> in <module>()
    1 lista = [1,2,3,"hey","woot",2.44]
----> 2 print (" ".join(lista))
    3 

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

When done with join:

```
lista = [1,2,3,"hey","woot",2.44]
print (" ".join(lista))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-235-f57f2c8c638f> in <module>()
    1 lista = [1,2,3,"hey","woot",2.44]
----> 2 print (" ".join(lista))
    3 

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

**It is stating that element at 0 index is int instead of string argument**

Internally what the `join` will do is it will iterate over the list(iterable objects) and append with prefix in this case `" " a space` and provide a string output `So finally "".join() does not support int/float`

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know how to use the join() in Python 3. (And why it needs a string)

Answer (score 4):

Alternative:

```
print (" ".join([str(x) for x in lista]))
```

but Anand S Kumar's version is better for Performance.

Answer (score 0):

> could anyone tell me why it supports ONLY strings?

Python (both 2.x and 3.x) is dynamically **but strongly** typed, so (unlike *weakly typed* languages where `'a' + 1` would be implicitly converted to `'a' + '1'` and hence `'a1'`) implicit type conversions simply do not happen:

```
>>> 'a' + 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    'a' + 1
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Note that [the documentation for `str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) reads (emphasis mine):

> Return a string which is the concatenation **of the strings** in the *[iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) iterable*.

To get around this, you need to *explicitly convert the elements to strings*, e.g. using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str, [1, 2, 3, "hey", "woot", 2.44]))
'1 2 3 hey woot 2.44'
```